# How to merge audio better?

Tags: audio, audio-processing, wave

I try to use a denoising algorithm to process an audio in streaming mode.
What I've done is spliting the audio into 0.5s long segments and use denoising algorithm respectively.Then use np.cat or np.hstack to merge them together.But in this way,the resulting audio will have a lot of spikes.And the resulting spectrum will have a lot of vertical lines.

How can I improve this?

the original noisy audio is below:
[image]

If I don't use the cross-fade,the result will be like this:
[image]

I've tried to use sqrt-based cross fade to do this.like the following:

```
    sqrt_fade_in = np.sqrt(np.linspace(0, 1, overlap_len))
    sqrt_fade_out = np.sqrt(np.linspace(1, 0, overlap_len))
    for i in range(num):
    noisy_data = noisy_data.squeeze(0)
    if i == 0:
        data = noisy_data[:chunk_size]
    else:
        data = noisy_data[i * (chunk_size)-overlap_len:(i + 1) * chunk_size-overlap_len]  #silde:chunk_size-overlap_len
    data = data.unsqueeze(0)
    start_time = time.time()
    result_data = enhance_one_track(data)
    #--------------overlap with cross-fade--------------#
    fade_out = overlap_data[-overlap_len:]*sqrt_fade_out
    fade_in = result_data[:overlap_len]*sqrt_fade_in
    print(time.time() - start_time)
    if i == 0:
        result[:chunk_size] = result_data
    else:
        result[(i-1) * chunk_size:(i + 1) * chunk_size-overlap_len]=np.concatenate(
            (overlap_data[:chunk_size-overlap_len],fade_in+fade_out,result_data[overlap_len:chunk_size]),axis=None
        )
    overlap_data = result_data
```

But it didn't work out well.

[image]
After that, I also tried to zero fill the audio before and then feed it into the algorithm for processing, and finally cut off the filled part when connecting the audio.

```
def zero_padding(noisy_data,overlap_rate,chunk_size=8000,padding_rate=0.1):
    # # The slices are fed to the algorithm for processing
    overlap_len = int(chunk_size*overlap_rate)
    num = int(noisy_data.shape[1] / chunk_size)
    result = np.zeros((noisy_data.shape[1],))
    # Sets the length of the padding data
    padding_len = int(chunk_size*padding_rate)
    for i in range(num):
        noisy_data = noisy_data.squeeze(0)
        data = noisy_data[i * (chunk_size):(i + 1) * chunk_size] 
        data = pad_audio(data,padding_len)
        data = data.unsqueeze(0)
        start_time = time.time()
        result_data = enhance_one_track(data)
        # result_data = hpss(result_data)
        # plt.plot(result_data)
        # plt.show()
        result_data = result_data[padding_len:-padding_len]
        # result_data = hpss(result_data)
        print(time.time() - start_time)
        # merge
        result[i * (chunk_size):(i + 1) * chunk_size]=result_data
    return result
```

The end result is as follows:
[image]
I have also tried to combine the above two ways：
[image]

These are the efforts I've made, but they don't work very well.

Comment: I have no idea what your denoising alg does, so my question is, for all of the frequency components left over after denoising, are they phase aligned with what they were before the denoising took place?

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson I use a deep learning alg named CMGAN.I think the phase will change.link is here:github.com/ruizhecao96/CMGAN

Comment: Could you add a plot of the orginal noisy signal? Also, to systematically assess the performance, use a clean audio signal to which you add noise yourself. This way you have a clean reference and can calculate all kinds of metrics, e.g. SNR.

Comment: Also interesting: what happens, if you don't do any crossfade at all? So, no overlap. How bad are the artifacts?

Comment: @Max Thank you for your suggestion.In fact its a task of my internship.My leader just gives me the noisy video and tells me to use the pretained-model of  CMGAN to do the experiment.The audio is not just include human voice,so maybe the effect of denoiser itself is not so good.

Comment: @Max I update the plot you need.

Comment: The version with no crossfading doesn't look any worse, than the one with it. You could try some nonelinear stuff, like taking 100 samples at each side of the cut and do some interpolating to align them, eliminating the clicks. Overlapping does not seem to help, since the denoising alg is nonlinear itself.

Comment: I would support to try something like @Max suggest. You only need to make sure that no clipping occurs due to your interpolating.

Comment: @Max Thank you so much.I will try it.

Comment: @Max May I ask you a question?How to do some interpolating to align them?

Comment: @MatthiasLa Thank you very much for your advice. But I'm sorry I don't quite understand what clipping is, I'm new in this field, and I'm not sure what scene is translated into the Chinese term.

Comment: @Killuaisaack: I'll write this into an actual answer, this is too long for a comment.

Comment: @Killuaisaack: Clipping means that your signal values exceed the possible range. For instance in a wave-file only values between -1 to +1 are possible. So if your interpolation function would lead to values outside that range your signal will be "clipped" to +1 or -1. This will lead to simillar vertical lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your denoising algorithm seems to be nonlinear in what it is leaving behind. The leftover noise is not phase aligned with the original noise or the noise of the next chunk. So, by overlapping and adding you essentially sum two uncorrelated signals, boosting the noise level by 3dB.

Additionally, it may well be that this is the case for the signal part as well. This leads to discontinuities in the overlapping parts, which will sound like clicks or cracks audiowise.

The first problem (noise adding up) can be tackled by not using overlap. This leaves the second problem, the discontinuities. Perceptively, these cracks can be worse than short gaps in the signal depending on their level.

They can be addressed by a smoothing interpolation to even out the discontinuitys. The python package `scipy` has a rich toolbox for this, `scipy.interpolate`.
Plain linear interpolation will not do the trick, as it does not take into account the first derivative of the samples, leaving discontinuities behind. A good starting point to try out seems to be `scipy.interpolate.make_interp_spline`. It is quite powerful. Have a look at the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.make_interp_spline.html) as well as this [well documented example](https://jorchard.github.io/interp/simple_spline.html). With this, you should get the idea of what to do.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I still have a bit of confusion, I also tried other interpolation functions before you answered, after using these interpolation functions, I will get an interpolation curve. Should I resampling to get discrete points and then insert them into my audio interface to change the result?

Comment: In principal, yes. Look at the example. This:  `xx = np.linspace(x[0],x[-1],100)
yy = [cs(x) for x in xx]` does what you say.