# How can I use interpolation to align audio

Tags: audio, interpolation

I notice that when I connect two audio clips, there is a jump at the junction.

[image]
How do I use interpolation to connect these two pieces of audio?

Thanks for the answers, I've got an answer from my other question：
[How to merge audio better?](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/89206/how-to-merge-audio-better/89235?noredirect=1#comment191632_89235)

Some related information:

1.Noise is the sound of aircraft propellers 2.I want to cut the noisy audio into 0.5s audio, and then feed it into the algorithm to denoise. Then connect the denoised segments.
The denoising alg is CMGAN.link is here:github.com/ruizhecao96/CMGAN

a plot of both signals I am trying to connect:
[image]
[image]

Comment: what do you mean by *"align these two pieces of audio"*?  do you want to remove the click or do something else?

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson Yes,I want to remove the click.

Comment: Many DAW software, as like Coscos Reaper, has a tool called 'join' which does the job quite well... . https://www.reaper.fm/

Comment: Didn’t you get an answer here? [How to merge audio better?](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/89206/how-to-merge-audio-better)

Comment: @Jdip Yes, so I edited it into my question because I didn't want to delete my question

Comment: But it’s the same question… why are you asking the same question twice?

Comment: @Jdip Yes, just as you said. But I didn't realize it was the same question when I asked it, and Max didn't answer me at that time. I'm sorry I made this mistake, but deleting the problem doesn't seem to be allowed by this site?

Comment: Ah I see ok. Yes you can delete this question. Otherwise the kids will do it for you, don’t worry ;)

Comment: @Killuaisaack: the two clips seem to have about 40 dB difference in level. Is that really the case? That would seem fairly odd

Comment: I meant the mods, not the “kids”!

Answer (score 0):

A straightforward(ish) approach is cross-fading: apply a fade-out at the end of the first clip and a fade-in at the beginning of the second. Overlap the two sections that fade in/out, which will gradually blend the two together.

You can experiment with linear/logarithmic fade curves, and of course with the fade duration.

Comment: I've tried the cross-fade, but it doesn't work very well.

Comment: What do you mean by “*doesn’t work very well*”?

Comment: The jump at the junction did not improve, and the noise increased.

Comment: Can you post a plot of both signals you are trying to connect please? What noise are you talking about? What are these audio clips? Please edit your question with more information!

Comment: 1.Noise is the sound of aircraft propellers 2.I want to cut the noisy audio into 0.5s audio, and then feed it into the algorithm to denoise. Then connect the denoised segments.The denoising alg is CMGAN.link is here:github.com/ruizhecao96/CMGAN

Comment: Sorry for not giving enough information

Comment: That’s ok, but I don’t understand, Max answered this question already in your previous question!